# Ubuntu Server - Client Desktop Environment

Tags: server

I've got a Computer with Ubuntu server installed and then i've got several other computers receiving the OS image through network.
I've tried this in the past but i did this with thin clients, and this time i'm trying to create Fat clients.

I created a *.Desktop file and put it inside 
`/opt/ltsp/amd64/usr/share/xsessions`.

i did  this in 2 ways:

- in the thin client it appeared in the sessions menu(Login Screen)
- in the fat client it didn't

My question is: why?
Did it changed the folder in which xsession should be or what?